# Is there any paper explaining which machiine learning algorithms needs scaling in data pre-processing?

Tags: references, feature-scaling

I can see on many blogs and tutorials that data scaling (e.g standardization) allow better performance for logistic regression and neural networks, but does not improve tree-based models (classification tree, random forest) performance. But is there any good references (papers) that I could cite in an article to support this?

Comment: Unfortunately, the short answer is no unless you can find a review paper. Data scaling and pre-processing are scientific fields within themselves. Your best bet is looking at textbooks, which are a more reliable source of information (such as Pattern Recognition and Machine Learning by Christopher Bishop). Those books will generally provide a good explanation of the concepts while also citing the relevant academic literature which you can then read.